# neohapsis "distcrack" applet : what does it do? Suspicious!

Tags: security, browser, java

I went to this page on neohapsis about the [latest Linux kernel bug](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/fulldisclosure/2009-08/0174.html). I kept this URL opened in a tab and I noticed that my CPU was at full load... Weird. Then after looking around for a while I notice "Applet DistCrack.class started", WTF? I promptly banned it with AdBlock+.

Edit: I just noticed that they mention their "research on distributed computing" on the page. This is a bit harsh to me : suck up CPU first and opt out later?

Comment: Damn skippy.  These people are bad citizens, at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the link and reached the page with **firefox**.

- Noticed nothing suspicious active on my system
- Opened [**NoScript**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722) for `neohapsis.com`; *temporarily*

  - Still no new activity...
- Then, opened the "`blockable items`" list on [**AdBlock+**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865)

  - I could see the blocked item
    **`http://dc.suntzu.net/DistCrack.class`**
- Since I had opened NoScript specifically for the primary site (neohapsis),
  I **effectively opted out**.
- Would not even have noticed all this
  if I had been to that site without reference from this question

Short story: **If you are fine to run Ads from other Ad servers,

You probably do not mind giving some CPU time to distributed computing research** `:-)`
(this is probably their philosophy too)

If you want to opt-out of such things,
take suggestions from my description above.